# Android Constraint Layout jumping to the right side of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using `Constraint Layout` and trying to put things as shown at this picture:

[image]

The thing is when I start it up, the last `00` that is above the word `stars` jumps to the right side of the screen. And since they are all connected everything else follows. 
But the thing is in my opinion they should all depend on the element on their left but they all still follow the `00` above the word `stars`.

Since I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time I thought I had understood `Constrain Layout` incorrectly.

Here is the `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/sdvProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:failureImage="@drawable/edit_profile_profile_default_image"
        fresco:failureImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/edit_profile_profile_default_image"
        fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
        fresco:roundedCornerRadius="0.5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/llPostsCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/_00_text"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sdvProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/posts"
        android:textColor="@color/regularTextColora5a7aa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llPostsCount" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFollowersCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="00"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/llPostsCount"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sdvProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/followers"
        android:textColor="@color/regularTextColora5a7aa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFollowersCount" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFollowingCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="00"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvFollowersCount"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sdvProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/following"
        android:textColor="@color/regularTextColora5a7aa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFollowingCount" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEditProfile"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_rcorner_white_box_lgray_ltgray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/EDIT_PROFILE"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        fresco:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.178" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_stars"
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="00"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvFollowingCount"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sdvProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_stars_text"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/userstars"
        android:textColor="@color/regularTextColora5a7aa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_stars" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What am I doing incorectly?

**EDIT**

I got a emulator to screenshot the result I get and it did not look as bad as it did on the phone but still not I want:

[image]

Sorry for the bad quality but this is what I am getting from the phone:

[image]

Comment: Can you also show a sample of what you are getting?

Comment: I am sorry it took so long but I tried to download the emulator to get a better quality picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add `fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/some-id"` to the middle items. So that all four items can be centered horizontally. For example, `TextView` with id `allPostsCount` should have `fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvFollowersCount"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/sdvProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:failureImage="@drawable/edit_profile_profile_default_image"
        fresco:failureImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/edit_profile_profile_default_image"
        fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
        fresco:roundedCornerRadius="0.5dp" 

        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/llPostsCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/_00_text"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvFollowersCount"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sdvProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/posts"
        android:textColor="@color/regularTextColora5a7aa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView5"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llPostsCount" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFollowersCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="00"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/llPostsCount"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvFollowingCount"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sdvProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/followers"
        android:textColor="@color/regularTextColora5a7aa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView3"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFollowersCount" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFollowingCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="00"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvFollowersCount"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/user_stars"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sdvProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/following"
        android:textColor="@color/regularTextColora5a7aa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFollowingCount" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEditProfile"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_rcorner_white_box_lgray_ltgray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/EDIT_PROFILE"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        fresco:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.178" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_stars"
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="00"
        android:textColor="@color/balck282828"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvFollowingCount"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sdvProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_stars_text"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/userstars"
        android:textColor="@color/regularTextColora5a7aa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        fresco:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fresco:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        fresco:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_stars" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do the added pictures help or is your answer the same, since I tried adding what you told me to and I started looking wierd.

Comment: It should still work same. Constraining each item to other and constraining the outer items to the parents should help center them horizontally

Comment: But if I add it they just stick to the item I add the line to and they are right next to it?

Comment: set android width to 0

Answer (score 1):

Here some advices :

- Name your views more precisely. You should not use ids like `@+id/textView5` (which is the second view in the horizontal list of word), it's too much confusing to build your layout properly.
- You are specifying exact width to your textview so words are cut, prefer using wrap_content if you can.
- You used precise margins to center your `00` labels. If it seems to work on the layout editor, you won't expect the same result on all devices, especially on larger ones. You could rather center your items using constraints
- To build your layout I would use a packed Horizontal chain on the labels (because they are larger) https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#constrain-chain. Then you center the number according to their corresponding label.

Here's a result of what you can have following the last advice : [image: packed horizontal chain]

Keep trying, i'm sure you can do this !

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I will look into it.